# Add namespaces to serialized xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, namespaces, addition

I've got a pretty nasty problem with xml serialization - I need to add some special information to the resulting xml-file:

Currently, it looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ORDER_LIST>
  <ORDER version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0">... shortened ...</ORDER>
  <ORDER version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0">... shortened ...</ORDER>
  <ORDER version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0">... shortened ...</ORDER>
</ORDER_LIST>
```

**but it should look like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ORDER_LIST>
  <ORDER xmlns="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0 openTRANS_ORDER_1_0_all_in_one.xsd" version="1.0" type="standard">... shortened ...</ORDER>
  <ORDER xmlns="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0 openTRANS_ORDER_1_0_all_in_one.xsd" version="1.0" type="standard">... shortened ...</ORDER>
  <ORDER xmlns="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0 openTRANS_ORDER_1_0_all_in_one.xsd" version="1.0" type="standard">... shortened ...</ORDER>
</ORDER_LIST>
```

**The additional namespace (xmlns:xsi) and the xsi:schemaLocation / type attributes should be added to the result.**

Actually my code is:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0")]
public class OrderContainer
{
[XmlElementAttribute("ORDER")]
public List<ORDER> orderList;
}

---- snip ----

string xmlString;

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "\t",
    NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document,
};

XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
var testOrder = new ORDER();

var orderContainer = new OrderContainer();
orderContainer.orderList = new List<ORDER>();
orderContainer.orderList.Add(testOrder);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ORDER>), new XmlRootAttribute("ORDER_LIST"));

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, settings))
        serializer.Serialize(writer, orderList, ns);

    xmlString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}

Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
```

It works really fine - except for the namespaces and attributes on the ORDER elements.
Background-information: The ORDER class is created from the openTrans-definition ([opentrans_order_1_0_all_in_one.xsd](http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0/opentrans_order_1_0_all_in_one.xsd)).
It's been translated into C# classes using Xsd2Code ([Xsd2Code](http://www.codeplex.com/xsd2code/)).
Because of the automatic generation, adorning the class with attributes is not easily possible - I guess?

**Thanks for any hint!**
(Edited some information)

Answer (score 3):

I know its a little late to reply to this question, but nonetheless I am answering in case someone in need stumbles upon this question.

I order to add namespaces you need to use this class: System.Xml.Serialization. XmlSerializerNamespaces, which I see in the problem code that it has been defined.

Following is the syntax that I have used to add namespaces while dealing with the xCBL Xml Schema:

```
[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns;  //Defined as the Field of the class you want to serialize

//Defined in the Constructor
xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlns.Add("core", "rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/core/core.xsd");
```

This will add the namespace in the generated Xml like this:

```
xmlns:core="rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4_0/core/core.xsd"
```

Answer (score 1):

What it should look like is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ORDER_LIST xmlns:trans="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0 http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0 openTRANS_ORDER_1_0_all_in_one.xsd" version="1.0" >
  <trans:ORDER type="standard" >... shortened ...</ORDER>
  <trans:ORDER type="standard" >... shortened ...</ORDER>
  <trans:ORDER type="standard" >... shortened ...</ORDER> 
</ORDER_LIST>
```

I'm not familar with xsd2code, but if you were hand coding, you need to put attributes.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Order")]
public class Order() {
            String Type

        }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("OrderList", Namespace="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/1.0", IsNullable=false)]
public class OrderList() {
          List<Orders> 

        }
```

Comment: Can the information from the attributes also be put on the object using "normal" code?

Comment: Sam, sorry to say, but your code is mixing the qualification-scope for class and property attributes.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it's a libary to create or read opentrans documents!
http://opentrans.wordpress.com/